# Where does our spirit go when we are sleep? What happens to our spirit when we sleep?

Tags: death

We see dreams, rarely true dreams...or dreams that could make sense to some person who knows how to interpret it...is that related to our spirit being extracted from our body like death? What happens to our spirit?

I don't want opinions... only something that is backtracked to Quran or narrations

Comment: you wont be able to get very exactly right answers on it as few things are hidden for some good reasons.

Answer (score 4):

Salam. I think by spirit you mean soul. If yes, then you are right. When one sleeps, Allah takes his soul and may or not may not return it to his body. As Allah states in Quran: (39:42)

> [image: Blockquote]
>   Translation:
>   (Sahih International)
>   Allah takes the souls at the time of their death, and those that do not die [He takes] during their sleep. Then He keeps those for which He has decreed death and releases the others for a specified term. Indeed in that are signs for a people who give thought.

This ayyah declares that Allah takes souls in two forms: First soul from ones who died and second from those living ones who are alive during their sleep.

And Allah states: (6:60)

> [image: Blockquote]
>   Translation: (Sahih International) And it is He who takes your souls by night and knows what you have committed by day. Then He revives you therein that a specified term may be fulfilled. Then to Him will be your return; then He will inform you about what you used to do.

There are some ahadith as well but I think these two ayyah especially the first one clears the point. Could I help you?

Comment: i doubt that the soul leaves the body while we sleep. it is scientifically incorrect. Death and Sleep both are different.

Comment: @Zia I got curious by your comment. When did science prove presence of soul?? And by the way, death is really different from sleep. In sleep, soul doesn't go out from body completely rather the life in person proves that there is a part of soul in body but not completely..

Comment: @Zia
I agree with you that they are different, but don't you agree that they are similar in many ways? As they are put close together in the Quran as well?

Comment: @Vazir Wow!! Glad to hear which I couldn't think of before. They are different but similar as well in many ways!!