# Were our souls created when we were born?

Tags: soul, human-body

From what I know about Islam (which I learned from my parents mostly), we have a soul and our soul is different to our physical body form (right?).  It is something that can leave our body when we are asleep.

So I wanted to ask if our souls existed before we were born or was it created when we was born?

Comment: This is a very extensive and intricate philosophical topic and has been subject to historical debate among muslim theist philosophers. The most advanced and coherent theory, though, has been presented by a 17th century Iranian theist philosopher Mulla Sadra. Here is a paper that exposes his theory: [The Soul as *Barzakh*: Substantial Motion and Mulla Sadra's Theory of Human Becoming](http://www.readcube.com/articles/10.1111%2Fj.1478-1913.2004.00043.x?r3_referer=wol&tracking_action=preview_click&show_checkout=1&purchase_referrer=onlinelibrary.wiley.com&purchase_site_license=LICENSE_DENIED)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where does our spirit go when we are sleep? What happens to our spirit when we sleep?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/26095/where-does-our-spirit-go-when-we-are-sleep-what-happens-to-our-spirit-when-we-s)

Answer (score 3):

The soul is something we don't know much about. As a matter of fact, almost nothing. Probably once we have better technology we will understand a little of it like Allah mentions:

[image]

> And they ask you, [O Muhammad], about the soul. Say, "The soul is of the affair of my Lord. And mankind have not been given of knowledge except a little." [17:85]

First there is the soul, then the body. Once combined, the person is created. In regards to Adam PBUH, his soul was created after his body was created:

[image]

> Indeed, the example of Jesus to Allah is like that of Adam. He created Him from dust; then He said to him, "Be," and he was.[3:59]

However, for normal people, the soul was created before the soul.

Arabic Source: http://www.saaid.net/Doat/almgamce/26.htm

Comment: Material technology can never grasp the nature of human soul! Matters of metaphysics are just outside the scope of natural science and tech. Their only conceivable use would be in the study of different affects of human psychic/spiritual conditions on his bodily/humoral/neurological conditions.